# HERE Batch geocoding stuck on accepted status

Tags: geocoding, here-api

Using the [HERE](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/introduction.html) batch geocoding REST API, I've submitted a job to geocode 4 addresses using the `action=run` parameter and got a `RequestId` back in the response. When visiting the API endpoint for the job's status via the following URL...

```
https://batch.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/jobs/[RequestId]?action=status&app_id=[app_id]&app_code=[app_code]
```

...I get the following response:

```xml
<ns2:SearchBatch xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Search-Batch/1">
  <Response>
    <MetaInfo>
      <RequestId>[RequestId]</RequestId>
    </MetaInfo>
    <Status>accepted</Status>
    <TotalCount>0</TotalCount>
    <ValidCount>0</ValidCount>
    <InvalidCount>0</InvalidCount>
    <ProcessedCount>0</ProcessedCount>
    <PendingCount>0</PendingCount>
    <SuccessCount>0</SuccessCount>
    <ErrorCount>0</ErrorCount>
  </Response>
</ns2:SearchBatch>
```

There's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46104628/52509) here on SO with the same problem, and was addressed in an answer from [ckHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196810/52509):

> Status "accepted" means that your job has been queued and is waiting
>   for a slot to execute. We at HERE are monitoring the queues to make
>   sure that capacity is adjusted as needed.
>
> So I guess that your application is ok and the bottleneck was probably
>   on our side.

What's troubling is some of the other answers in questions related to this issue, particularly how long it could take for the job to finally get processed.  [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48615661/52509):

> Looks like it's a queue issue, except mine has been going on for
>   nearly a week. HERE API never runs batch job, always returns accepted
>   status
>
> *4 days later*
>
> It was a queue issue. ...all the jobs suddenly
>   completed simultantously. Service has been working fine ever since.

Which leads into my questions:

1. Should I assume MY problem right now is on HERE's end, or could I still be doing something wrong when I created the job (and how could I find out)?
2. If the problem is indeed on HERE's end, how often does this happen? Is HERE generally pretty reliable and is just having a hiccup in their services this weekend, or can I expect days (weeks?) long delays in jobs on a regular basis?
3. Does HERE have a status page where I can check if any of their services are having problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the answers to your questions in bullets.

1. Should I assume MY problem right now is on HERE's end, or could I still be doing something wrong when I created the job (and how could I find out)?
   **Yes, the problem is due to some bad jobs getting submitted and blocking all other jobs as they have to wait for already running job.**
2. If the problem is indeed on HERE's end, how often does this happen? Is HERE generally pretty reliable and is just having a hiccup in their services this weekend, or can I expect days (weeks?) long delays in jobs on a regular basis?
   **This shouldn't happen often since we have basic checks in place and constantly improvising the checks to avoid such problems**
3. Does HERE have a status page where I can check if any of their services are having problems?
   **Unfortunately, no. We don't provide an external dashboard to view the services or job running**

Hope you find them useful.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I should also mention those jobs did eventually complete.  The weird part is that even though it took days for the status to change, the actual start and end timestamps in the response shows the job completed in seconds after I started it.  Anyway, I'm happy to report I haven't had any problems since then.